# How to maintain image aspect ratio and quality while converting images to base64 string in android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-bitmap

My code works but not the way I want. What I want is a bit of improvement to achieve better solution. Uploading images from files to to remote server renders poor quality image with small dimensions. I have tried different solutions including Stack Overflow suggestions but none of those solutions helped me. So what I want is to upload large images to remote server maintaining aspect ratio without OOM.

Am using this code:

```
public String resizeBase64Image(String base64image){
        byte [] encodeByte=Base64.decode(base64image.getBytes(),Base64.DEFAULT);
        BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPurgeable = true;
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length,options);


        if(image.getHeight() <= 400 && image.getWidth() <= 400){
            return base64image;
        }
        image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, 200, 200, false);

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, baos);

        byte [] b=baos.toByteArray();
        System.gc();
        return Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.NO_WRAP);

    }
```

and;

```
private String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);

        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        return resizeBase64Image(Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT));
    }
```

This renders poor  quality images. When I try to change this line`image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, 200, 200, false);` to `image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, 300, 300, false);` volley registers an error.
Anyone with a better solution can assist me on better method to handle `base64 String` without OOM or may be improve on my code.

Comment: are you scaling image from 200x200 to 300x300 ??

Comment: no am scaling depending on the image size. `image.getHeight()` and `image.getWidth()`

Comment: If you want to scale image, say reduce by half size, you can do it like `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, image.getWidth()/2, image.getHeight()/2, true);`
I think if you are trying to scale small image to a larger value, the resulting image will be distorted